# Infinite loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop

I have a problem with jQuery, for some reason, that code makes infinite loop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function changeURL() {
        location.href = 'http://aaa.com';
    }

    $('#daysLeftSort').change(changeURL());
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When assigning an event handler, assign the *function* reference directly, not the *result* of the function, so leave off the `()` (which calls the function immediately...reloading the page), like this:

```
$('#daysLeftSort').change(changeURL);
```